# TCHAR* envp[]: What is it?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, main-method

I created a VC++ console project with Visual Studio and it auto-generated this function:

```
int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[], TCHAR* envp[]) { ... }
```

I was just wondering what **`envp`** stands for and how/when I can/should use it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `envp` argument above will store the environment variables.

> The envp array, which is a common
>   extension in many UNIX® systems, is
>   used in Microsoft C++. It is an array
>   of strings representing the variables
>   set in the user's environment. This
>   array is terminated by a NULL entry.
>   It can be declared as an array of
>   pointers to char(char *envp[ ]) or as
>   a pointer to pointers to char(char
>   **envp). If your program uses wmain instead of main, use the wchar_t data
>   type instead of char. The environment
>   block passed to main and wmain is a
>   "frozen" copy of the current
>   environment.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88w63h9k(v=VS.71).aspx)